# Throw exception for duplicate child within same parent in a xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I am having an XML in the follwing format.

Sample XML:

```
{
    <message>
        <parent1>
          <child>A</child>
          <child>B</child>
          <child>C</child>
        </parent1>
        <parent2>
          <child>A</child>
          <child>B</child>
          <child>B</child>
        </parent2>
    </message>
}
```

Desired Output:

> Exception: Parent 2 contains duplicate child.

Please help me in writing the XSLT code to perform validation on the XML.

**Update**

This is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/> 
  <xsl:template match="parent"> 
    <xsl:copy-of select="*" />  
    <xsl:for-each select="child"> 
      <xsl:variable name="node_child" select="text()"/> 
      <xsl:variable name="numEntries" 
                    select="count(../child[text()=$node_child])"/> 
      <xsl:if test="$numEntries &gt; 1"> 
        <xsl:text>Child value of </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text> has multiple entries &#xa;</xsl:text> 
      </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XML validation is usually done in [XML schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) not in XSLT. It is something like `<xsd:element name="child" maxOccurs="1">`. Google how to write an XML schema.

Comment: What have you tried?  It's easy enough to do this in XSLT (and probably a little harder with XSD validation), but you won't learn anything if you don't try to solve the problem yourself before asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="child
                     [some $s in preceding-sibling::* 
                     satisfies deep-equal(., $s)]">
  <xsl:message terminate="yes"
    >Dying:  duplicate element <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing above code. I would follow your word going forward.  Above code is good for 2.0 version but I require some method for 1.0 version. Is it possible for you to suggest me I am having below code, but it is printing error twice, can you help in modifying it.

Comment: {   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="parent">
<xsl:copy-of select="*" />         
<xsl:for-each select="child">
<xsl:variable name="node_child" select="text()"/>
 <xsl:variable name="numEntries" select="count(../child[text()=$node_child])"/>
<xsl:if test="$numEntries &gt; 1">
<xsl:text>Child value of </xsl:text><xsl:text> has multiple entries &#xa;</xsl:text> 
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>
}

Comment: Sorry; didn't notice the 1.0 tag on the question.  If you have two elements which are the same by your test, your code is issuing the error message once for each of them.  If you check for duplicates only among elder siblings (use `preceding-sibling::child` not `../child`), you will get the error only once.  Note that identity of some text() node is really a very weak (and error-prone) test for duplication.  It may work for your data, but it does not work in general.